# Keep text centered in parent in ConstraintLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to achieve a very simple top bar layout in Android's `ConstraintLayout`:

There is a back button (can be hidden), there is a right button (can be hidden) and there is a text title shown in the middle. **Most importantly,** I want to keep the text centered in the parent.

However, when I'm tying the borders of the views, the title text gets pushed from the center since left and right views have different sizes:

[image]

As you can see, the `TITLE` is not centered in the parent. The texts in the working solution should also not overlap each other, obviously, and the title should be ellipsized. So it's like an "advanced barrier" pushing from both sides - the one that is bigger will force the title to get smaller, but the title will always be in the middle.

One way of doing it would be to make left and right views of equal width and the rest would be given to the title view, however I couldn't find a way to make two views in different areas of equal width.

Is this even possible in `ConstraintLayout`? It's easy to do in iOS's Autolayout system, but it's much more powerful than Android's `ConstraintLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

*however I couldn't find a way to make two views in different areas of equal width*

If you want to achieve something like this you can use:

`app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.x"` to tell your views what size to be according to the screen size (and keep it responsive).

For example something like this (I made it with support library but it will work with androidx as well):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="<"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="x"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It will look something like this:

[image]

Now your 2 buttons take exactly 10% of the screen width and you can tell your text view to expand and take the remaining width(`android:layout_width="0dp"`).

### But what if I will have very large text?

In that case, if you want to keep your layout responsive you can use [ssp(https://github.com/intuit/ssp) library.

> An android SDK that provides a new size unit - ssp (scalable sp). This size unit scales with the screen size based on the sp size unit (for texts). It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.